# Visual Studio 2019: Browser not reloading after save

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I'm making a React application and I'm currently using Visual Studio to run the program and VSCode to edit the code.
When I used to save changes on VSCode, it automatically refreshed the browser with the changes I did. But recently it stopped working and now I have to make a manual reload (F5).

Here's what I've tried so far without success:

- Updated both programs to their latest version.
- Deleting the file and downloading it again from Gitlab.
- In Visual Studio: Tools > Options > Environment > Documents cheked the boxes to detect changes outside enviroment.
- Delete and generate again the .vs folder
- Tried on a different browser
- Tried making changes in Visual Studio
- And so on ...

I tried with a similar app I built and that one was working fine and using the same properties.
There's currently two of us working on the project, but this issue only happens to me.

Comment: How do you start react in visual studio?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend running the React from **VSCode**, using `npm start` / `yarn start` from command line in the directory.

Try changing something and see if the browser automatically reloads.